# How to display element with animation when it is in the viewing area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm wondering how to do something like this?

http://themeforest.net/item/cheeky-ajax-loading-one-pager-template/full_screen_preview/7751172

When you scroll down, elements are showing up on the screen with animation. Could someone give me a simple example of sth like this ?

Comment: Use this JQuery - http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/. It help you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use this lib http://scrollrevealjs.org/

Comment: That is exactcly what I was looking for! Thx !